# No Row Selected Problem - JOIN and SUBQUERY in SQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I've been trying to solve the following problem:

**Write a query to display list of subject names and minimum mark scored in 'Software Engineering' and 'Computer Programming' . Give an alias name as MIN_MARK for minimum mark column. Sort the result based on subject name in descending order.**
[image]

And this is the code I've tried to solved the aforementioned problem:

```
select s.subject_name, min (m.value) as MIN_MARK
from mark m
join subject s on m.subject_id = s.subject_id 
where m.subject_id in (select subject_id from subject
                       where subject_name = 'Software Engineering' 
                       and subject_name='Computer Programming') 
group by s.subject_name;
```

And I'm getting the output --> `No Rows Selected` 
Could anyone please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: *where subject_name = 'Software Engineering' and subject_name='Computer Programming'* this means , result would be the rows where subject_id has both the values above, but from the description it seems not quite right to me. Maybe change it to *where subject_name in ('Software Engineering','Computer Programming')*

Comment: @ErgestBasha It worked! Thank you very much. Could you please tell me what was the issue?

Comment: [s]he just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you please tell me what was the issue?

As I mentioned in the comment the problem is the where filter.

```
where subject_name = 'Software Engineering' 
  and subject_name = 'Computer Programming'
```

> Can the same row be 'Software Engineering' and 'Computer Programming'
> simultaneously ?

Answer. **No**

You have to change the where filter from `and` to `or` (which ca be written easily as in) .

```
where subject_name in ('Software Engineering','Computer Programming')
```

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/u_aR6mDS)